# Error bootstrapping the device Error code=8

Tags: apk, windows-10-mobile, lumia

I was trying to install apk on my windows phone 10 ( Lumia 435 ). But while pairing the device I struck on error

> Error bootstrapping the device Error code=8

Googled but nothing found appropriate